# Includeonly for files in subdirectory

Tags: chapters, include

I have a book and I have all my chapters stored in a subdirectory `chapters`. How do I use `\includeonly` on those files? My current attempts have not been working.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\includeonly{chapters/01.tex} %% this doesn`t work
%\includeonly{01.tex} %% this also didn't work

\begin{document}
\input{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\include{chapters/01}
\include{chapters/02}
\include{chapters/03}
\include{chapters/04}
\include{chapters/05}
\include{chapters/06}
\include{chapters/07}
\include{chapters/08}
\include{chapters/09}
\include{chapters/10}

\backmatter
\input{credits}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the `.tex` extension, otherwise LaTeX searches for `01.tex.tex`

Comment: @karlkoeller can you tell me why the instructions are wrong here? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/includeonly

Comment: @karlkoeller your suggestion worked though. If you want to write it as the answer I will accept it. Otherwise I'll write the answer myself.

Comment: I don't have any idea why WikiBooks suggests that. I've always known that it is wrong. But probably in some OS it works that way (I've always used Windows). And anyway I've converted the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commands `\include` and `\includeonly` expect a "filename" as an argument, not a "filename.filetype". The filetype `.tex` is added by the commands themselves.

So if you write

```
\includeonly{chapters/01.tex}
```

LaTeX searches for the file `chapters/01.tex.tex` and doesn't find it.

To solve the problem, simply don't specify the extension, as in

```
\includeonly{chapters/01}
```

so LaTeX will search for the right file (`chapters/01.tex`).

Note that `\input` behaves in a different way. In fact,

```
\input{file}
```

and

```
\input{file.tex}
```

is the same. Both refer to the file `file.tex`.